# WorldWind support for right click context menu

Tags: java, swing, worldwind

Here is an example from the NASA WorldWind project:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 United States Government as represented by the Administrator of the
 * National Aeronautics and Space Administration.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 */
package gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples;

import gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.avlist.*;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.event.*;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Position;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.RenderableLayer;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.*;
import gov.nasa.worldwindx.applications.worldwindow.util.Util;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Illustrates how to attach context (popup) menus to shapes. The example creates several <code>{@link
 * PointPlacemark}s</code> and assigns each of them a context-menu definition. When the user presses the right mouse
 * button while the cursor is on a placemark, the placemark's context menu is shown and the user may select an item in
 * it.
 *
 * @author tag
 * @version $Id$
 */
public class ContextMenusOnShapes extends ApplicationTemplate
{
    /** The Controller listens for selection events and either highlights a selected item or shows its context menu. */
    protected static class ContextMenuController implements SelectListener
    {
        protected PointPlacemark lastPickedPlacemark = null;

        public void selected(SelectEvent event)
        {
            try
            {
                if (event.getEventAction().equals(SelectEvent.ROLLOVER))
                    highlight(event, event.getTopObject());
                else if (event.getEventAction().equals(SelectEvent.RIGHT_PRESS)) // Could do RIGHT_CLICK instead
                    showContextMenu(event);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Util.getLogger().warning(e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : e.toString());
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings( {"UnusedDeclaration"})
        protected void highlight(SelectEvent event, Object o)
        {
            if (this.lastPickedPlacemark == o)
                return; // same thing selected

            // Turn off highlight if on.
            if (this.lastPickedPlacemark != null)
            {
                this.lastPickedPlacemark.setHighlighted(false);
                this.lastPickedPlacemark = null;
            }

            // Turn on highlight if object selected.
            if (o != null && o instanceof PointPlacemark)
            {
                this.lastPickedPlacemark = (PointPlacemark) o;
                this.lastPickedPlacemark.setHighlighted(true);
            }
        }

        protected void showContextMenu(SelectEvent event)
        {
            if (!(event.getTopObject() instanceof PointPlacemark))
                return;

            // See if the top picked object has context-menu info defined. Show the menu if it does.

            Object o = event.getTopObject();
            if (o instanceof AVList) // Uses an AVList in order to be applicable to all shapes.
            {
                AVList params = (AVList) o;
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (ContextMenuInfo) params.getValue(ContextMenu.CONTEXT_MENU_INFO);
                if (menuInfo == null)
                    return;

                if (!(event.getSource() instanceof Component))
                    return;

                ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu((Component) event.getSource(), menuInfo);
                menu.show(event.getMouseEvent());
            }
        }
    }

    /** The ContextMenu class implements the context menu. */
    protected static class ContextMenu
    {
        public static final String CONTEXT_MENU_INFO = "ContextMenuInfo";

        protected ContextMenuInfo ctxMenuInfo;
        protected Component sourceComponent;
        protected JMenuItem menuTitleItem;
        protected ArrayList<JMenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();

        public ContextMenu(Component sourceComponent, ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo)
        {
            this.sourceComponent = sourceComponent;
            this.ctxMenuInfo = contextMenuInfo;

            this.makeMenuTitle();
            this.makeMenuItems();
        }

        protected void makeMenuTitle()
        {
            this.menuTitleItem = new JMenuItem(this.ctxMenuInfo.menuTitle);
        }

        protected void makeMenuItems()
        {
            for (ContextMenuItemInfo itemInfo : this.ctxMenuInfo.menuItems)
            {
                this.menuItems.add(new JMenuItem(new ContextMenuItemAction(itemInfo)));
            }
        }

        public void show(final MouseEvent event)
        {
            JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();

            popup.add(this.menuTitleItem);

            popup.addSeparator();

            for (JMenuItem subMenu : this.menuItems)
            {
                popup.add(subMenu);
            }

            popup.show(sourceComponent, event.getX(), event.getY());
        }
    }

    /** The ContextMenuInfo class specifies the contents of the context menu. */
    protected static class ContextMenuInfo
    {
        protected String menuTitle;
        protected ContextMenuItemInfo[] menuItems;

        public ContextMenuInfo(String title, ContextMenuItemInfo[] menuItems)
        {
            this.menuTitle = title;
            this.menuItems = menuItems;
        }
    }

    /** The ContextMenuItemInfo class specifies the contents of one entry in the context menu. */
    protected static class ContextMenuItemInfo
    {
        protected String displayString;

        public ContextMenuItemInfo(String displayString)
        {
            this.displayString = displayString;
        }
    }

    /** The ContextMenuItemAction responds to user selection of a context menu item. */
    public static class ContextMenuItemAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        protected ContextMenuItemInfo itemInfo;

        public ContextMenuItemAction(ContextMenuItemInfo itemInfo)
        {
            super(itemInfo.displayString);

            this.itemInfo = itemInfo;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println(this.itemInfo.displayString); // Replace with application's menu-item response.
        }
    }

    // The code below makes and displays some placemarks. The context menu info for each placemark is also specified.

    public static class AppFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame
    {
        public AppFrame()
        {
            RenderableLayer layer = new RenderableLayer();

            // Create and set an attribute bundle.
            PointPlacemarkAttributes attrs = new PointPlacemarkAttributes();
            attrs.setAntiAliasHint(Polyline.ANTIALIAS_FASTEST);
            attrs.setLineMaterial(Material.WHITE);
            attrs.setLineWidth(2d);
            attrs.setImageAddress("images/pushpins/push-pin-yellow.png");
            attrs.setScale(0.6);
            attrs.setImageOffset(new Offset(19d, 11d, AVKey.PIXELS, AVKey.PIXELS));

            PointPlacemarkAttributes highlightAttrs = new PointPlacemarkAttributes(attrs);
            highlightAttrs.setScale(0.7);

            ContextMenuItemInfo[] itemActionNames = new ContextMenuItemInfo[]
                {
                    new ContextMenuItemInfo("Do This"),
                    new ContextMenuItemInfo("Do That"),
                    new ContextMenuItemInfo("Do the Other Thing"),
                };

            PointPlacemark pp = new PointPlacemark(Position.fromDegrees(28, -102, 1e4));
            pp.setAttributes(attrs);
            pp.setHighlightAttributes(highlightAttrs);
            pp.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.CLAMP_TO_GROUND);
            pp.setValue(ContextMenu.CONTEXT_MENU_INFO, new ContextMenuInfo("Placemark A", itemActionNames));
            layer.addRenderable(pp);

            pp = new PointPlacemark(Position.fromDegrees(29, -104, 2e4));
            pp.setAttributes(attrs);
            pp.setHighlightAttributes(highlightAttrs);
            pp.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
            pp.setValue(ContextMenu.CONTEXT_MENU_INFO, new ContextMenuInfo("Placemark B", itemActionNames));
            layer.addRenderable(pp);

            pp = new PointPlacemark(Position.fromDegrees(30, -104.5, 2e4));
            pp.setAttributes(attrs);
            pp.setHighlightAttributes(highlightAttrs);
            pp.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
            pp.setValue(ContextMenu.CONTEXT_MENU_INFO, new ContextMenuInfo("Placemark C", itemActionNames));
            layer.addRenderable(pp);

            pp = new PointPlacemark(Position.fromDegrees(28, -104.5, 2e4));
            pp.setAttributes(attrs);
            pp.setHighlightAttributes(highlightAttrs);
            pp.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
            pp.setValue(ContextMenu.CONTEXT_MENU_INFO, new ContextMenuInfo("Placemark D", itemActionNames));
            layer.addRenderable(pp);

            // Create a placemark that uses all default values.
            pp = new PointPlacemark(Position.fromDegrees(30, -103.5, 2e3));
            pp.setValue(ContextMenu.CONTEXT_MENU_INFO, new ContextMenuInfo("Placemark E", itemActionNames));
            layer.addRenderable(pp);

            // Add the layer to the model.
            insertBeforeCompass(getWwd(), layer);

            // Set up the context menu
            ContextMenuController contextMenuController = new ContextMenuController();
            getWwd().addSelectListener(contextMenuController);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationTemplate.start("World Wind Context Menus on Shapes", AppFrame.class);
    }
}
```

I am trying to refactor the `ContextMenu` code to support an arbitrary action for `ContextMenuItemAction`. I would like to be able to use an anonymous class something like ActionListener is often used in Swing code. Can this code be refactored easily to support that? The intent is to avoid having to create whole classes for each action in the menu.

Comment: Not sure I follow - Isn't AbstractAction what you are already looking for? How else would you want to define an action for the context menu? Do you have a related set of actions that can be specified in a single AbstractAction implementation and then specify which action to execute based on some passed in enumerated value?

Comment: I'd like to be able to something like `new ContextMenuActionItem() { @override actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ //do my action}};);`

Comment: @JadChahine: Imports are not "additional code": they are key to an MCVE. Please **do not** remove them. Furthermore, it should be obvious that removing licence/copyright/attribution information is a violation. Your edits are being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312045/560648).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want to create an abstract class that you can use as an anonymous inline class:

```
package gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ContextMenusOnShapes.ContextMenuItemInfo;

public abstract class ContextMenuItemAction extends AbstractAction
{       
    protected ContextMenuItemInfo itemInfo;

    public ContextMenuItemAction(ContextMenuItemInfo itemInfo)
    {
        super(itemInfo.displayString);
        this.itemInfo = itemInfo;
    }

    public abstract void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event);
}
```

Usage:

```
new ContextMenuItemAction(itemInfo) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Add Action Here!!
    }
}));
```

Comment: I agree that is what I want, but given the code that is there you can't instantiate a ContextMenuItemAction directly. That was my main problem. It is created for you in the makeMenuItems method.